# mocking up method return invoked in a separate thread using Mockito

Tags: java, multithreading, mocking, mockito

I'm having a problem mocking up a method return value on my mock object invoked in a new thread. In my test I have :

```
@Test
public void startConnectionTest(){

    clientConnection.startConnection();
    when(config.getUpdateInterval()).thenReturn(1000L); 
}
```

The startConnection method creates a new thread which calls a config.getUpdateInterval(). However the mock up value is not returned. The mock method return is called only once back in the main thread, which is too late. If I replace it with a real object then it works fine. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: So if it works with a real object, then you don't need a mock, right?

Comment: Shouldn't you simply mock the method before starting the thread?

Comment: JB spot on, I called it before starting the thread and it works.